# Does MATLAB's TreeBagger perform cross validation?

Tags: matlab

I'm wondering if MATLAB's [TreeBagger](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/treebagger.html) performs cross validation?

If so, what are the default parameters that TreeBagger uses for this?

Comment: This sounds like something you should ask the MATLAB support, or at least on [MATLAB Answers](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/?term=TreeBagger).

Comment: You probably want an ensemble of bagged trees, i.e. for regression see: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitrensemble.html#namevaluepairarguments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cross validation can be applied to TreeBagger using the [crossval](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/crossval.html) function.

[fitctree](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitctree.html) also has a cross validation option.

TreeBagger does not perform cross validation itself.